# Python: Lambda function as a namedtuple object?

Tags: python, lambda, namedtuple

I've written a program in which I have a fairly typical class. In this class I create multiple namedtuple objects. The namedtuple objects hold many items, which all work fine, except for lambda functions that I try to bind to it. Below is a stripped down example and the error message that I am receiving. Hope someone knows why this is going wrong. Thanks in advance!

**FILE: test.py**

```
from equations import *
from collections import namedtuple

class Test:
    def __init__(self, nr):
        self.obj = self.create(nr)
        print self.obj.name
        print self.obj.f1(2)

    def create(self, nr):
        obj = namedtuple("struct", "name f1 f2")
        obj.name = str(nr)  
        (obj.f1, obj.f2) = get_func(nr)
        return obj

test = Test(1)
```

**FILE: equations.py**

```
def get_func(nr):
    return (lambda x: test1(x), lambda x: test2(x))

def test1(x):
    return (x/1)

def test2(x):
    return (x/2)
```

**ERROR:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    test = Test(1)
  File "test.py", line 8, in __init__
    print self.obj.f1(2)
TypeError: unbound method <lambda>() must be called with struct instance as first argument (got int instance instead)`
```

Comment: Are you aware that your `get_func` has an unused `nr` argument?

Comment: @Martijn - yeah, just realized that the `x` is the `lambda` argument, so I edited my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `namedtuple()` constructor returns a *class*, not an instance itself. You are adding *methods* to that class. As such, your lambda's must accept a `self` argument.

In any case, you should create instances of the named tuple class you created. If you don't want to give your lambdas a `self` first argument, adding them to the instance you then created would work fine:

```
from equations import *
from collections import namedtuple


Struct = namedtuple("struct", "name f1 f2")


class Test:
    def __init__(self, nr):
        self.obj = self.create(nr)
        print self.obj.name
        print self.obj.f1(2)

    def create(self, nr):
        obj = Struct(str(nr), *get_func(nr))
        return obj

test = Test(1)
```

Comment: Can't argue with you on that one! +1

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: And it wasn't even the real issue. The real issue is using `namedtuple`-generated classes as instances.

Comment: @MartijnPieters perfect answer - feel free to nitpick on mine :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes, it is a common gotcha if namedtuple is defined inside a function.